# CSS/jQuery: background color for JUST the text in an input

Tags: jquery, css

I have some readonly inputs. I want JUST the text in these inputs to have a background color. Is there a way to accomplish this with CSS/jQuery? I've tried:

```
$('.show input').contents().css('background-color', '#F0444D');
```

and

```
$('.show input').children().css('background-color', '#F0444D');
```

But neither did anything.

Comment: There's no way to access the text object within an in `input`, either the whole `input` element gets the background colour, or nothing does.

Comment: @user460847 What do you mean by "JUST the text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lynxforest's answer you can set the background of the whole field to a certain colour.

I understand you want just the text to have the background colour, not the whole field. But that's not possible in an INPUT field. In another kind of element such as a DIV you could insert a SPAN tag:

```
<DIV class="box"><SPAN>blabla</SPAN><DIV>
```

but INPUT fields can have no other elements as content so this trick doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use divs to make it look like a readonly input. I'll accept you when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
$('.show input').css('background-color', '#F0444D');
```

Answer (score 1):

this will only set a background color with texted fields

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) $(this).css('background', '#CCC')
})
```

Comment: [`$('input:text')`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) for a more concise version.

Comment: yeah, you are right, but this version is also works properly.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't intending to criticise, just offer a pointer/suggestion for a less-typing approach is all. Sorry if I offended you, that wasn't my intent. =)